# How to encode this string to JSON?

Tags: perl, json

I have this JSON string

```
$json_string = qq{{"error" : "User $user doesn't exist."}};
```

which I construct in a low level way, so to speak.

How do I encode it using the JSON module?

Right now I encode hashes like this

```
use JSON;
my $json_string;

my $json = JSON->new;
$json = $json->utf8;

my $data;
$data->{users}  = $json->encode(\%user_result);
$data->{owners} = $json->encode(\%owner_result);
$json_string    = to_json($data);

print $cgi->header(-type => "application/json", -charset => "utf-8");
print $json_string;
```

Comment: Why are you double-encoding your JSON?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ratna is right - you can not encode a simple string (unless you put it in a list or hash)

Here are a couple of variants to encode your string:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON;

my $user = "Johnny";

my $json_string = { error_message => qq{{"error" : "User $user doesn't exist."}} } ;
$json_string    = to_json($json_string);
print "$json_string\n";

#i think below is what you are looking for
$json_string = { error => qq{"User $user doesn't exist."} };
$json_string    = to_json($json_string);
print $json_string;
```

Answer (score 1):

JSON should be either `{key:value}` or `[element]`

The given error string:

```
qq{{"error" : "User $user doesn't exist."}}
```

is invalid as far as I know.

Comment: But decoding the string back to object might be a problem if it doesn't follow the JSON format.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if the functionality was added after the responses, but you CAN encode a json string using perl, using the JSON module.

Using allow_nonref:

```
$json = $json->allow_nonref([$enable])

$enabled = $json->get_allow_nonref
```

> If $enable is true (or missing), then the encode method can convert a
>   non-reference into its corresponding string, number or null JSON
>   value, which is an extension to RFC4627. Likewise, decode will accept
>   those JSON values instead of croaking.

Code and quote from https://metacpan.org/pod/release/MAKAMAKA/JSON-2.90/lib/JSON.pm#allow_nonref